# crunch wordlist generation with all combinations

Tags: shell, utilities, backtrack, truecrypt, words

I'm trying to generate a wordlist in order to use it to bruteforce my own Truecrypt container. I do know parts of the password, its built up using blocks of other known passwords to increase length, but I forgot in which order the blocks were used and if some blocks weren't used at all.

Example "blocks" separated with space: `dog cat bird xyz cow1 lion8`

What I would like to do is create a wordlist containing each possible combination of these blocks. E.g

```
dog
cat
dogcat
catdog
bird
dogbird
catbird
birdcat
birddog
dogcatbird
catdogbird
xyz
dogcatbirdxyz
cow1
xyzcow1dogcat
xyzcow1dogcatbird
catdogbirdxyzcow8
lion8
catdogbirdxyzcow1lion8
lion8catdogbirdxyzcow1
dogcatbirdxyzcow1lion8
cow1birddogcatxyzlion8
cow1lion8birddogcatxyz
...
```

So far I've tried to utilize a tool called crunch: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-r1-man-pages/crunch

But the challenge seems to be how one should generate combinations of shorter combinations, not including all known blocks, example: `dogcat` only includes 2 blocks.

Perhaps someone know `crunch` better than me, or if I should use another tool or combination of tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes),

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from itertools import chain, permutations
# from the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
# modified for permutations instead of combinations


def powerset_perm(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(permutations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s) + 1))


for w in powerset_perm(sys.argv[1:]):
    print("".join(w))
```

Example:

```
~ ./foo.py foo フー bar1™
foo
フー
bar1™
fooフー
foobar1™
フーfoo
フーbar1™
bar1™foo
bar1™フー
fooフーbar1™
foobar1™フー
フーfoobar1™
フーbar1™foo
bar1™fooフー
bar1™フーfoo
```

Comment: Awesome! This looks very promising. I will try this out when I get the chance, I'll follow up afterwards. Is there any limit on what characters that are supported? E.g special characters, numbers etc?

Comment: @NiklasJ It's Python 3, so it should handle all valid Unicode characters I think.

Answer (score 2):

`crunch` currently only supports permutations and not combinations. I recommend doing this with `perl` and `Math::Combinatorics`, e.g.:

```
words=(dog cat bird xyz cow1 lion8)

# Generate all possible combinations of $words
perl -MMath::Combinatorics -E '
  $, = " ";
  for $i (1 .. @ARGV) {
    say @$_ for(combine($i, @ARGV));
  }
' ${words[@]} |

# For each combination, get all possible permutations
perl -MMath::Combinatorics -anE 'say @$_ for (permute(@F))'
```

Run it with `| shuf -n20`, the output is sometimes:

```
lion8dogxyzcow1cat
birdcow1catlion8xyz
catxyzlion8cow1
catdoglion8xyz
doglion8cow1birdxyzcat
birdcow1lion8dogxyzcat
xyzcow1dogcat
birddogcat
dogcatxyzcow1
catxyzdogcow1
birdcatxyzlion8dogcow1
cow1xyzlion8
cow1catlion8xyzbirddog
xyzlion8catdogcow1bird
dogcow1catxyzbirdlion8
xyzcow1dogcatbirdlion8
cow1birdlion8dogcat
lion8cow1catbird
xyzbirdcatcow1
xyzdogcow1lion8birdcat
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like another good option. My problem has already been solved however, but I still appreciate the knowledge :)